# RxJava: List of Singles

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I got some trouble with RxJava. I am coding with Kotlin. Here is my problem:
I have a list of Singles. Now I need the emitted results of all Singles to proceed.
It would be great if the Singles could run in parallel and the results stay in the same order.
When all Singles emitted their result, I want to proceed.

```
val list_of_singles = mutableListOf<Single<Type>>()
val results: List<ResultType> = runSingles(list_of_singles)
// use results here...
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Did you mean `mutableListOf<Single<Type>>()`? and not `mutableListOf<Singles<Type>>()`?

Comment: what about `zip` operator ?

Comment: Also (judging from your code sample only) I think you're misunderstanding or trying to misuse RxJava here. You're mixing two concepts: synchronous and asynchronous code. List of `Single`s is a list of asynchronous operations, yet you expect `runSingles` to return a list of `ResultType`s synchronously?

Comment: @BartekLipinski I see what you mean. But it is kind of given by the architecture. It would be accebtable if the order get lost.

Comment: @Laufwunder what is given by the architecture? The list of `Single<Type>`? Or the need for synchronous `results`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
    val disposable = Observable.fromIterable(itemList).flatMapSingle { item ->
        getSingle(item)
            .map { singleResult ->
                // do something with single result
            }
    }.doOnComplete {
        // do stuff after processing all singles
    }.subscribe()

    addToCompositeDisposable(disposable)
```

It makes more sense working with the framework, than against it.

Answer (score 6):

What about [Single#zip](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.2.19/io/reactivex/Single.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-)?

```
fun main() {
    val singles = listOf(
        Single.just(1),
        Single.just(2),
        Single.just(3)
    )
    val list : Single<List<Int>> = Single.zip(singles) {
        it.toList() as List<Int>
    }
    
    list.test().assertResult(listOf(1,2,3))
}
```